# How can I keep data models synchronized across iOS front-end, Node.js API, and PostgreSQL database?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, database, xcode

Coming from a .NET background, synchronizing data models across an n-Tier project was a breeze. I could leverage Entity Framework and T4 templates to automatically generate POCOs (DTOs), whenever a table's attributes were modified. Necessary project layers could then access these up-to-date models at will.

I'm wondering if it's possible to accomplish this level of synchronization across the following technologies - iOS (xCode) frontend, Node.js API server, and a PostgreSQL database?

Sourcery (https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery) seems like a solid library for Swift iOS code generation, though I'm unsure about wiring with PostgreSQL. I'm also scratching my head with the PostgreSQL --> Node.js piece as well.

Has anyone worked through this problem before? Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Why the down vote? If you could elaborate or point in a general direction, I think that would be better for others facing similar challenge, no?

Comment: Maybe someone thought it was too general or something. I don't think so though.

Comment: It shows that 2 people thought it was "too broad".. I don't think so as it's a unique problem and it seems like you want a "Reactive" binding.. Basically you want the changes in the database to trigger a "generation" of the structure models to represent the tables? AFAIK CoreData has this.. but PostgreSQL, I'm not so sure tbh..

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the comments. Understood on the broadness and I think the best approach may be focusing on generating Swift models from JSON within the Node.js API project, initially. Between Sourcery, SwiftGen (https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen), and Quicktype (https://quicktype.io/), I think I should be able to get a POC working.